# How to get a transparent background in IE8 and IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, gradient

i'm looking for a replacement for the below code in IE8

```
background-color: rgba(0, 143, 213, 0.9);
```

So after searching in internet i found this

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#E5008FD5,endColorstr=#E5008FD5)";
```

now the problem is if i use the above filter the transparency in IE9 is getting lost

Can anyone guide me to get the transparency in IE8 without effecting other browsers.

Here is my code

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .parent{
        color:white;
        //filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FFFF0000,endColorstr=#FFFF0000);
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#FFFF0000,endColorstr=#FFFF0000)";
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
    }
    .child{
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        //filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#E5008FD5,endColorstr=#E5008FD5);
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#E5008FD5,endColorstr=#E5008FD5)";
        background-color: rgba(0, 143, 213, 0.9);

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
<h3>how are you</h3>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

edit:

I observed
IE10

```
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
```

IE9

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#FFFF0000,endColorstr=#FFFF0000)";
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
```

IE8

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#FFFF0000,endColorstr=#FFFF0000)";
```

in IE9 both are getting applied. that's why it is looking as solid color in IE9. If i can remove anyone it is working fine. But don't how to make it in specific browser

Comment: Can you just use a tiny transparent PNG image as a repeating background?

Comment: I would like to make it possible with above filter.If i don't use filter transparency in IE9 working perfectly.  If i use filter it stops working.